# Use choose file with choose file sheet (as in NSOpenPanel)

Tags: applescript-objc

I would like to know if there is a possibility to use choose file like "Choose file sheet" if the answer is yes could you give me an example?

Comment: The various sheet methods currently use blocks, but AppleScriptObjC doesn’t support those yet (still).  If you are using an Xcode project, a third party Objective-C category can be added.

Comment: Looking at [this old post at MacScripter](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=193440#p193440) it may be possible to display a sheet on a window using deprecated methods. The deprecated methods don't use blocks — possibly the reason they are deprecated — so should work. I'll have to play with a bit to see if I can make it happen.

Comment: @TedWrigley I tried using [Myriad Helpers](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/helpers.html)  but I didn't succeed,I found it very interesting and with many features.

Comment: @red_menace I tried this, show me a alert ```set myAlert to current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
                        tell myAlert
                            its setDelegate:me
                            its setShowsHelp:true
                            its setMessageText:"Main alert message."
                            its setInformativeText:"Main alert informative text."
                            its beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow modalDelegate:me didEndSelector:(missing value) contextInfo:(missing value)
                        end tell```

Comment: @TedWrigley Did you play with that a little?

Comment: @TheOnlyOneHere: I did play a bit. I can get about 90% of the way there just in vanilla ASOC — make and attach a sheet, access the results (sort of: can't get a handle on whether the user clicked *Ok* or *Cancel*) — but I can't seem to get didEnd selector to to hook up with anything in the script. I've started trying to make it work as a cocoa-applescript applet, but no luck so far (I haven't really used those before, so there's a bit of a learning curve).

Comment: @red_menace  let me know, something else I would like to know how to get the button clicked from the from the NSAlert example up there for example if I click
on the quit button he quits the program or does something else

Comment: The sheet is not synchronous, so the script doesn’t wait for the result.  You will need to provide either a modal sheet category or a handler for the `didEndSelector` to get a return value.  You have strayed a bit from your original `NSOpenPanel` topic, so perhaps you should start a new topic with what you are trying to do with `NSAlert`.

Comment: @red_menace, you are right, i will start a new topic and hope for your answers, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheets are a bit of a pain with AppleScriptObjC, but [Myriad Helpers](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/helpers.html) helps a lot.
To use the **NSOpenSave+MyriadHelpers** category, add their .h and .m files to your Xcode project using the **File > Add Files to …** menu item.  From a new (default) AppleScript App project, for example, you could do something like:

```
on applicationDidFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    tell current application's NSOpenPanel's openPanel()
        its setMessage:"Please select a file:"
        its setPrompt:"Choose"
        its setDirectoryURL:(current application's NSURL's fileURLWithPath:(POSIX path of (path to desktop)))

        its setCanChooseFiles:true
        its setCanChooseDirectories:false
        its setAllowsMultipleSelection:true
        its setAllowedFileTypes:{"png"} -- list of extensions or UTIs

        its showOver:theWindow calling:{"panelCompletion:", me}
    end tell
end

on panelCompletion:openItems
    if openItems is missing value then -- "Cancel" button
        log "Cancel"
        return -- or whatever
    end if
    repeat with anItem in openItems as list
        log anItem -- do your thing with the individual file paths
    end repeat
end panelCompletion:
```

Comment: I have the following using choose file ```set allFiles to choose file with prompt "Please select a file:" with multiple selections allowed
            repeat with theFile in allFiles```  I can verify that the selected file is of a certain extension and then I save this file in another folder, but I don't know how to proceed with NSOpenPanel.

Comment: Using the Myriad Helper category, you set up the `NSOpenPanel` with the desired options (don’t forget that you can use methods from the parents), and the completion method specified for the `showover:calling:` method will be passed a list of the chosen file paths (or missing value if canceled).  From there you can repeat through the list as usual.  I’ve edited my answer to include your options.